# Not able to get user name in telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

The name comes out as none. Can someone please help

```
def funtion_example(update, context):
    #name of the bot user
    chat_user_client = update.message.from_user.username
    update.message.reply_text(str(chat_user_client))
```

Comment: Post entire code.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [bot api docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) you will see that only `first_name`, `id` and `is_bot` are not marked as *Optional*.

Thus a number of users will not have a username, which you have to take into account and work around.

Answer (score 0):

if you are retriving message from channel you can try `sender_chat`, in this you will have username of channels and real users, instead in the `from_user` you will find username of real users and bot. So you need to choose which one use depending of the use-case.

```
def funtion_example(update, context):
    #name of the bot user
    chat_user_client = update.message.sender_chat.username
    update.message.reply_text(str(chat_user_client))
```

- [from_user](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.user.html#telegram.User) doc
- [sender_chat](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chat.html#telegram.Chat) doc